# React Styled Components - How to access raw html

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a ref on a component I am converting over to a [styled component](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) in my app. The ref is used to access the offsetHeight and scrollHeight properties on the raw html element of the component. Once I switched this component to a styled component, the ref now points to the styled component instead of the raw html element, and I'm unsure how to reference the base element. Can this be done?

example:

```
const TextArea = styled.textarea`
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0 18%;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  width: 64%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #111;`;

export default class Input extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const height = this.textInput.scrollHeight;
    // do something....
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextArea
          ref={(input) => this.textInput = input}
        ></TextArea>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Passing `ref` to a styled component will give you a ref to the `styled-components` wrapper, not the DOM node. To get a ref to actual DOM node **pass the innerRef prop**. (see [the docs](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/1fb841ac84cd3093ffef4b1db383d46418dd1bfe/docs/tips-and-tricks.md#refs-to-dom-nodes))

This is what you need to do:

```
const TextArea = styled.textarea``;

export default class Input extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const height = this.textInput.scrollHeight;
    // do something....
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextArea
          innerRef={(input) => this.textInput = input}
        ></TextArea>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Note that as of 4.0, you can use `ref` instead of `innerRef`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. You can access raw html using [`ReactDOM.findDOMNode()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode). However, bear in mind that the use of this method is discouraged. You can read more about this in the referenced page.

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression this api was being deprecated. Is that not the case?

Comment: I'm not sure, but there's no mention of that in the docs. Do you have a reference?

Comment: I'll see if I can find it and get back to you. I do remember it being stated that it is discouraged, as you mentioned as well.

Comment: It was not depreciated. It was removed from 'react' module and is now available in 'react-dom' module