# React - How do you get the top position of a styled component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Something that used to be simple is quite complicated when you don't know the *React* way.

I'm trying to create a component to act like a sticky header or footer when it reaches the top of the page.

At the moment I'm quite content in adding the below:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, false);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, false);
  }
```

However I've hit a wall to how I get the scroll top position of a styled component. So lets say I had a styled component called `Container` and that outputted a form I usually just add a data attribute and do something like the below:

```
const container = document.getElementbyTag("data-sticky-container")
const position = container.offsetTop
```

How would I go about doing this in React?

---

### Update

Now using `ref`. I've fallen into a problem where current isn't defined:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.optionBox = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, false);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, false);
  }

  onScroll() {
    console.log(this.optionBox.current.offsetTop);
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In react you would use a reference for your component: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

You would have something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  getOffset = () => {
    console.log(this.myRef.current.offsetTop);  
  }
  render() {
    return <Container ref={this.myRef} onClick={this.getOffset} />;
  }
}
```

And now you can access the container offsetTop by `this.myRef.current.offsetTop` inside of your `onScroll` function like in `getOffset`

Comment: do you know why offsetTop would be undefined?

Comment: sorry - you need to do `this.myRef.current.offsetTop`

Comment: I'm getting an undefine on the current now. I'll update my answer with some more info. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: I think you need to bind `onScroll` like this: `this.onScroll = this.onScroll.bind(this);` in your constructor

Comment: ah your right! This has got me a few times! Thanks Laurenz

Comment: No problem - by the way: if you use arrow functions like `onScroll = () => {}` you don't have to bind the function. More about this: https://reactarmory.com/answers/when-to-use-arrow-functions

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an innerRef. This can be better because it will give you a reference to the DOM node and not just a wrapper. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42533074/7663531).

You would then have more direct access to properties like `scrollTop`.

Unlike `ref`, `innerRef` uses a callback:

In your case it would look like:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef;
  }

  getOffset = () => {
    console.log(this.myRef.offsetTop);  
  }

  render() {
    return <Container
        innerRef={element => this.textInput = element}
        onClick={this.getOffset} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **ref**
to the component for which u want an offsetTop. This ref will have all the computed css values of that component.